# Dependent ComboBoxes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to have a word document that has 2 comboboxes. Combobox1 will have a selection and the second will be populated dependent on Combobox1's selection.

The following code executes the legacy controls style, but I want active x combo boxes. I also have a constraint that comments need to be able to be entered in the word doc, and restricting form fields disables that (why the legacy style won't work).

```
   Sub Dropdowns()
    Dim xDirection As FormField
    Dim xState As FormField
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xDirection = ActiveDocument.FormFields("QSystem")
    Set xState = ActiveDocument.FormFields("FType")
    If ((xDirection Is Nothing) Or (xState Is Nothing)) Then Exit Sub
    With xState.DropDown.ListEntries
        .Clear
        Select Case xDirection.Result
            Case "Type1"
.Add "SubType1"
.Add "SubType2"
              Case "Production and In-Process Controls"
.Add "SubType3"
.Add "SubType4"
                 End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So why not use content controls and 'No changes (read only)' protection or 'Comments' protection and the appropriate exceptions?

Comment: ActiveX combo boxes are the same as the combo boxes for a UserForm. There are lots of questions/discussions/examples for what you're asking in the context of UserForms. Try some of those, to get started. Then you need to specify how this "form document" will be used, because that affects where the code goes and its syntax.